# Check if arms are raised Zigfu and Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect

Using [Zigfu](http://zigfu.com/) in Unity3D, how can I check if arms are raised?

Comment: Haven't used Zigfu in Unity3D, but I presume it uses OpenNI/NITE behind the scenes and there's an "arm raised" gesture defined in NITE

Answer (score 3):

I am unfamiliar with [Zigfu](http://zigfu.com/), but if there is not already a back-end mechnism to test for this fact (as [George Profenza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89766/george-profenza) points out in the comments) then you could easily roll your own test that would test for this condition.

Each of the Kinect APIs (official or 3rd party) have a breakdown of joints for the skeleton.  The [official API](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/) breaks the skeleton into the following joints, and I believe that [NITE](http://www.primesense.com/solutions/nite-middleware/) breaks the skeleton into the same joints.

[image: Kinect Skeleton Joints]

You can test the position of one joint against the position of another joint to see if  your "arms raised" condition is met.

For example, you can simply check if the player's elbows are above their shoulders:

```
private void OnSkeletonFrameReady()
{
    if ((JointId[ElbowRight].Y > JointId[ShoulderRight].Y) &&
        (JointId[ElbowLeft].Y > JointId[ShoulderLeft].Y)
    {
        // arms have been raised
    }
}
```

This is obviously pseudo-code, that would need to be updated to the Zigfu API references.

The advantage of rolling your own (versus using something that might already be defined) is that you can decide what "arms raised" means.

- Do just the hands need to be above the shoulders?
- Do both the hands the elbows need to be above the shoulders?
- Do the hands just need to be above the `HipCenter` or `Spine` joint?
- Must the arms be extended, or can the elbows be bent?

All other those (and more) could be defined as "arms raised".  A configuration of joints can be tested against to determine if they are true.

If you wanted to make sure the player keeps their "arms raised" for a period of time before recognizing the state, you could simply add a timer to the gesture check.  A pseudo-code example being:

```
DispatherTimer _gestureTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
_gestureTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
_gestureTimer.Tick += OnGestureTimerTick();

bool _armsRaisedFlag = false;

private void OnSkeletonFrameReady()
{
    if ((JointId[ElbowRight].Y > JointId[ShoulderRight].Y) &&
        (JointId[ElbowLeft].Y > JointId[ShoulderLeft].Y)
    {
        _argsRaisedFlag = true;
        _gestureTimer.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        _armsRaisedFlag = false;
        _gestureTimer.Stop();
    }
}

private void OnGestureTimerTick()
{
    _gestureTimer.Stop();
    if (_armsRaisedFlag == true)
    {
        // player's arms have been raised long enough for gesture to pass
    }
}
```

In this case, each time the "arms raised" condition is met a flag is set and a timer is started.  If the player keeps their arms raised for 5-seconds, the condition is met and you can do what actions you want.

Answer (score 1):

Its sipmle, Just chek the ZigSkeleton file.

In the ZigSkeleton file, create a varialbe to store the id of the shoulder

```
public int TrackedLeftArm = (int)ZigJointId.LeftArm;
```

while in the UpdateRotation function,

```
Quaternion newRotation = transform.rotation * orientation * initialRotations[(int)joint];
```

now check

```
if((int)joint==TrackedLeftArm)
{


   if(newRotation.x> DesiredANgle)
    Debug.Log("Hands raised");

}
```